http request works inside android studio , but doesn't work on emulator and real phone ( kotlin , ktor )
I have watched many videos about sending http request in android studio, they involved "ktor" , "retrofit" , "HttpURLConnection" , "okhttp" , etc....   they all seam to work fine inside android studio , but they dont work on emuator on real phone.
When i run the script inside android studio ( Run 'MainActivity.kt' ) it works as expected, but when i build the apk and run app on emulator or real phone it doesn't work. ( the app seems to not have internet access i think )
here are the files and code relevant to the situation :
res -> xml -> network_security_config.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">com.example.httprequesttest</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>

androidManifext.xml :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ......
        ......
    </application>

</manifest>

com.example.httprequesttest -> MainActivity.kt :
package com.example.httprequesttest

.....
.....
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.engine.android.Android
import io.ktor.client.engine.cio.CIO
import io.ktor.client.request.get
import io.ktor.client.statement.HttpResponse


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {


    private lateinit var textView: TextView
    private lateinit var getButton: Button
    private lateinit var postButton: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {

            HttpRequestTestTheme {
                Scaffold(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) { innerPadding ->
                    Greeting(
                        name = "Android",
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPadding)
                    )


                }
            }
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        getButton = findViewById(R.id.getButton)
        postButton = findViewById(R.id.postButton)

        getButton.setOnClickListener {

            textView.text = "status code : $statusCode"
        }


    }


}


var statusCode: String = "nothing yet"
suspend fun main() {
    val client = HttpClient(Android)
    val response: HttpResponse = client.get("https://ktor.io/")
    statusCode = "status: ${response.status}"
    println(statusCode)
    client.close()
}

build.gradle.kts :
......
......
dependencies {

    ......
    ......

    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:2.3.12")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:2.3.12")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:2.3.12")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:2.3.12")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:2.3.12")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.6")

    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.3")



    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:2.3.12")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:2.3.12")
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:2.3.12")
}

so when i run code inside android studio , i get output in console :
status: 200 OK

Process finished with exit code 0

but when i run in emulator or real phone , the "statusCode" variable doesnt change it stays "nothing yet" and when click the "getButton" the "textView.text" changes from "Text View" to "nothing yet" instead of "status: 200 OK"
i am having the same problem with retrofit , HttpUrlConnection , okhttp , ect...
and if it try somehow to make http request from the "getButton.setOnClickListener{ // send get requets here }" the app crashes. (note: i did use runBlocking{ launch{ //send get request here } } , and still it crashed)
please help.
Thanks for everyone.
Update :
i am using :
getButton.setOnClickListener {
    runBlocking {
        launch {
            val client = HttpClient(Android)
            val response: HttpResponse = client.get("https://ktor.io/")
            textView.text = "status: ${response.status}"
        }
    }
}

when i click the button the app crashes, logcat shows the following error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.httprequesttest, PID: 9989
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getModule()Ljava/lang/Module; in class Ljava/lang/Class; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Class' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.EnvUtil.logbackVersionByModule(EnvUtil.java:56)
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.EnvUtil.logbackVersion(EnvUtil.java:36)
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    ..............
    ..............

i googled it but did not find anything usefull.
Please help.
Thanks again for everyone

"the app crashes" -- use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

thank you for your help, i updated the question and listed the logcat error, did not find solutions on google, looking for more help :)

When you run the app in emulator or phone the request is never made because function main is never executed.
If you call it from onCreate or any other lifecycle method, or as you already did, inside the click listener, the app might crash as you mention, in that case, as CommonsWare suggested,check the logcat to find the stack trace. And share it here if you don't understand the cause of the crash.

thanks you for your help, i updated the question and listed the logcat error, did not find solutions on google, looking for more help :)

The logback-classic starting with about version 1.4 throws the NoSuchMethodError in the Android environment. To solve this problem, you can use logback-android instead.

thank you for your help, the logback-android also failed and gave another error , but due to your help i was able to figue out that logback-core is the solution. changing from logback-classic to logback-core fixed the problem

In build.gradle.kts -> dependencies : change logback-classic to logback-core
the new build.gradle.kts should look like this :
......
......
dependencies {

    ......
    ......

    
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.5.6")

    .....
    .....
}

